# C#: Reflection-instantiated object throws casting error?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, reflection, casting

I'm working on a C# application that is supposed to examine other C# executables and assert, via unit tests, certain properties about the interfaces they expose. (For context, this is a grading application for a CS course; the assignment is to parse numeric ranges from a text file and return them according to a fixed interface.)

So far, I've managed to:

- Load the executable as a variable `assembly`, using `Assembly.LoadFrom(string)`
- Get the type of the interface in question, using `assembly.GetType(string)`
- Find an implementing type for the interface, again with `assembly.getType(string)`
- Instantiate the implementing type into a `dynamic` object, using `type.GetConstructor(Type[])` and `constructor.Invoke(Object[])`

At this point, I have a `dynamic` object `loader` that I know implements the interface I'm testing. I want to call one of the interface methods on `obj`, so I run:

```
dynamic rangeSet = loader.GetRangeSetFromFile (inputFile); // inputFile is a string
```

This throws an `InvalidCastException` with the following trace:

```
System.InvalidCastException : Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
at SwapAssignment3.Implementations.RangeLoaderAdapter.GetRangeSetFromFile (string) <IL 0x0001e, 0x00066>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.CallSite.Target (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,string) <IL 0x00036, 0x0007b>
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2<object, string, object> (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,string) <0x003cf>
at AssignmentTests.R3Test.TestLoadingViaInterface () [0x00054] in /Users/tim/Dropbox/Courses/CSSE375-TA/AssignmentTests/AssignmentTests/R3Test.cs:82
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&) <0x00003>
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) <IL 0x000db, 0x00147>
```

Why would this error be thrown? Running the executable in question works just fine on its own; this error is only thrown in the context of my testing application. The body of the `GetRangeSetFromFile` method is as follows:

```
public IRangeSet GetRangeSetFromFile(string filePath)
{
    var newRange = new RangeStorage();
    _fileProcessor.ProcessFile(filePath);
    newRange.StoreElements((List<IRange>) _fileProcessor.GetStorage());
    return newRange;
}
```

I have good reason to believe (from the program output, among other things) that the cast error is being raised from the third line, with the `List<IRange>` cast; however, since the trace gives IL locations, I'm not 100% sure of this, and I don't know why that cast would fail in the first place, since it works fine if the program is run on its own (outside my tester).

My primary question is: **why is this cast error being raised, and how can I avoid it?**

*Edit:* by request, the test code amounts to the following:

```
Type interfaceType = assembly.GetType("IRangeLoader");
List<Type> implementingTypes = new List<Type> (assembly.GetTypes ())
                                        .FindAll ((Type t) => t.IsClass)
                                        .FindAll ((Type t) => (new List<Type> (t.GetInterfaces ())).Contains (interfaceType));
Type implementingType = implementingTypes[0];
ConstructorInfo ctor = implementationType.GetConstructor (new Type[] {});
dynamic loader = ctor.Invoke (new Object[] {});
dynamic rangeSet = loader.GetRangeSetFromFile ("sample range.txt");
```

Comment: Is the dynamic `loader` type thought of as type `X`, or as of the interface `Y`? It might make a difference if the interface method is implemented explicitly.

Comment: Something to try: extract out a seperate line var storage = _fileProcessor.GetStorage(), and then in a debugger look at storage.GetType() to see if it's what you expect.

Comment: Is SwapAssignment3.Implementations.RangeLoaderAdapter something you're creating?  It looks like you're messing around with MSIL/Emit codes somewhere and those may be wrong.

Comment: @Tejs: I'm only trying to access methods defined in the interface on `loader`. For that purpose, I'm thinking of it as `Y`.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: It is indeed what I expect.

Comment: @ThinkingSites: That type is created in the assembly I load; it's the student's implementation of the interface in question.

Comment: Is there a competing `IRangeSet` interface in your testing application?

Comment: @Tejs: There used to be, but I removed it (figuring it might conflict). No change in the error.

Comment: Can you post more of the test invoking code?

Comment: Give me a minute or two to try reproducing this situation in a sample project on my machine.

Comment: If you know that `loader` implements a particular interface, any reason why you're not casting to that and taking the `dynamic` nature out of the question?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I'm not casting because the type is only defined in the loaded assembly, not in my project. I can't refer to that interface type statically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the following code seemed to work in invoking the method in another assembly:

```
Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(<path>);

var interfaceType = testAssembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.Name == "ISampleInterface").FirstOrDefault();

if(interfaceType != null)
{
    var implementingType = testAssembly.GetTypes().Where(typ => type.GetInterfaces().Any(iface => iface == interfaceType)).FirstOrDefault();

    if(implementingType != null)
    {
        dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(implementingType);

        dynamic result = obj.SampleInterfaceMethod();

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Try using some of this. I was able to call into that object and then get the result from that method back.

Comment: Does the method `SampleInterfaceMethod` do any casting? I feel like that's the error I'm running up against. Changing my own code to use `Activator.CreateInstance` instead of getting the `ConstructorInfo` still throws the same error.

Comment: Mine simply returned a string "HelloWorld" from an `object SampleInterfaceMethod()` interface contract. So in that sense, it was only boxing the type. What is the return type of `_fileProcessor.GetStorage()`?

Comment: It is of type `IRangeSet`, which is another interface guaranteed to be in the loaded assembly but not originally known to my tester project.

Comment: How is `IRangeSet` and `List<IRange>` even in the same type hierarchy then?

Comment: This is what happens when you trust students to submit working solutions. The tester is properly detecting an error because the student makes some illegal casts :) Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a great idea but it really seems like you are bending way too much in the students favor here.

You could provide an assembly (e.g., `CSxxxx.Interfaces.dll`) that you require your students to reference and implement.  Loading the implementations is pretty simple from there.

You could also provide a suite of tests that would likely yield a C or so if they all passed.  Then your suite would test everything.  If you were a little devious and could count on some of your students to extend given tests, you could then run StudentX's tests against all the other implementations and give bonus points for breaking other implementations.

Comment: While we do have a common set of interfaces they're required to reference, we are (unfortunately) developing the tester after the fact; all the submissions are already in, and we don't have anything shared to use. I'll definitely pass on this advice for next year's graders, though!